# How to convert DateTime value into Long number

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0

Is there any way to convert DateTime value into a Long number?

Like in Excel you will get 41016 for Apr 17, 2012.

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: If you're looking for a duplicate of a value output in Java, you should probably specify that in the question.  For that matter, what're you using this number for?  Is there a particular reason it has to match Java's output exactly?

Comment: @Jim: Thanks Jim. But i am not a Java guy. My client said he need date as a long value from my api which then he will convert back to datetime in Java. I just googled and found there is DateTime.getValue() that returns long value from date in Java and setValue() which converts back long into DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime has a Ticks property, which represents the date in a `Long`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

Edit based on your comment:

Maybe you need the `ToFileTime` method then? Otherwise I don't know what you mean

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx

Comment: Thanks Andrew! But i think it is not the same as we can get in Java.

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.Now.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Yuriy! But i think it is not the same as we can get in Java. Actually, I am creating APIs using ASP.Net which will be consumed for J2ME application. The client wants datetime in a long number format.

Comment: @IrfanRaza you labelled your question with C#, did you mean to label it with Java?